# How to differentiate between an areacode and the actual phone number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering is there a package or some way to differentiate between areacode and actual phone number in javascript/react?

For example:

```
"+16471234567" => "+1" "6741234567"
"+44 1234567890" => "+44" "1234567890"
```

Any help woudl be appreciated

Comment: Google maintains [a library to validate international phone numbers](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber), which I think would solve your problem. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library where you can find all country codes as per your requirements

[react-phone-input-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-input-2)

```js
 <PhoneInput
    country={'ye'}
    value={phoneNumber}
    onChange={(phone) => setPhoneNumber(`+${phone}`)}
    inputClass="INPUT_DESIGN_CLASSES"
    dropdownClass="DROPDOWN_LIST_CLASSES"
/>
```

You can find the demo here [Demo Link](https://yshop.cisstaging.com/) Go-to Signup -> Login with Phone